Application of hyperplane separation theorem and Riesz representation theorem.
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $C,D$  be tow disjointed convex compact subsets of $C(X,R)^* $ where the weak $^* -$ topology is used on $C(X,R)^*$,and the interior of C is not empty.
As hyperplane separation theorem,there exists a continuous linear functional $F\in C(X,R)^{**}$ such that $F(x)<F(y),x\in C,y\in D$.
Since we are using the  weak $^* - $ topology on $C(X,R)^*$ we know that $F$ has the form $F(x) = \int f d \mu$,for some $f\in C(X,R)$.[1,p223]
question:Is $C(X)$ a reflexive space? why the last sentence is ture?
reference
[1]Walters, P., 2000. An introduction to ergodic theory (Vol. 79). Springer Science & Business Media.
